# Boost::filesystem::is_symlink() does not work

Tags: c++, boost, symlink, boost-filesystem

When I launch this piece of code, it says that every file is regular, even symlinks :

```
cout<<boost::filesystem::is_symlink(boost::filesystem::status("link-name"))<<endl;
```

Anyone knows why ? (there is no warning nor error during the compilation)
The link was created with the command :

```
ln -s file-name link-name
```

and ls command says it is a link :

```
ls -l link-name
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myname mygroup 8 juil. 23 14:12 link-name -> file-name
```

Thanks !

EDIT : on the other hand, the function boost::filesystem::is_regular_file always returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `symlink_status(const path& p)` as in the [boost reference documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#symlink_status).

```
file_status symlink_status(const path& p);
```

> Returns: Same as status(), except that if the attributes
>   indicate a symbolic link, as if by ISO/IEC 9945 S_ISLNK(), return
>   file_status(symlink_file).

Comment: Indeed, with symlink_status(), is_symlink() returns true. But there we have to know the file status before runnin ... how can I know wether a file is regular or symlink durin execution ?

Comment: always use `symlink_status()`, it returns same as `status()` except symbolic link.

Comment: That's it ! symlink_status() works. Thanks ! But why status() does not returns the right file type ?

Comment: One may like to follow the symbolic link and determine the attributes of the target/real file. Boost provides 2 functions `symlink_status()` and `status()` to provide both.

Answer (score 2):

In the code you have `link_name`, in the filesystem you have `link-name`.